# Maasar that was set aside, and then stolen

Tags: halacha, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, gezel-stealing

If a person sets aside his Maasar in a seperate account, which was then stolen, or the bank folded and now it is worthless, does he have an obligation to replenish this account, or once set aside he fulfilled his obligation?

connected to [Is the Mitzvah of Tzedakah fulfilled in a fraud?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/is-the-mitzvah-of-tzedakah-fulfilled-in-a-fraud)

Answer (score 1):

The g'mara on Bava Metzia 6b discusses taking maasar from your animals and then they become mixed up, so you no longer know which ones were set aside.  In that case you do not tithe again because nine of ten animals were already designated as yours.  Reasoning by analogy, if you already set aside the money and then something happened to it, it seems like you don't then have to tithe again from the 90% you still have.

Of course, for practical matters consult your rabbi.

Comment: That's a little different, though, because (a) maaser of animals isn't tzedakah, and (b) the Gemara there (top of 7a) goes on to say that with maaser beheimah the Torah specifically implies that only a definite "tenth animal" has to be separated, not a doubtful one; this latter consideration wouldn't apply to maaser kesafim.