# Does charity which is misused by its recipient count?

Tags: tzedakah-charity, kavana-intent

Let’s say you give to charity and the charity wastes your money does it still count due to proper intention?

Comment: By the mishkan the commentaries explain that those who had the best intentions had their donations used for the more important things like the Aron etc and those who had less pure intentions were used for other things etc. so although you get a merit for giving charity regardless of what they do with it, there’s a special merit to have it used properly. However, that’s beyond your control and based on the level of purity of intentions

Comment: Who defines what's considered waste?

Comment: Charities like the Red Cross use a lot of the funds on themselves vs the actual TZEDAKAH

Comment: relevant and maybe duplicate of [Scrutinising the legitimacy/cause of a charity collector](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52820/11501)

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. All charities use funds on themselves, this is what enables them to do good for others. And paying x for a fundraiser who raises 10x is actually a good investment you want them to make. You are right that waste exists but not all money spent on themselves is waste

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10194/is-the-mitzvah-of-tzedakah-fulfilled-in-a-fraud